# What did a woman say in Casablanca film?

Tags: questions

I was watching Casablanca film and noticed that sometimes people speak in French. I have been learning French for half year therefore I enjoyed watching the film. I can't recognise one phrase. A woman says: "Comment ... vous?"

Here is the link to the moment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b71BVt6ayUE

Please help me. What did she exactly say and what the phrase means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's indeed quite hard to ear, but I think she said "*De quoi vous mêlez-vous?*"

Which means something like "*It's none of your business*".

Comment: Merci beaucoup!